# Concurrency - does jquery handler preserve queue?

Tags: jquery, concurrency, thread-safety

I have this easy [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5H9XT/) :

```
<a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a>​

$('#link1').click(function () {
    alert("First");
});

$('#link2').click(function () {
    alert("Second");    
});    
​
```

in a "remote" possiblity that a user click on Link1 (first) and than on Link2, with a difference of 0,000000001 ms (I know, is it impossible in the reality, but is just to know), is it possible that the alert of #link2 start before the alert of #link1?

And if yes, what's the solution to block handler of #link2 till the action of #link1 is it not finished?

Comment: If you don't want the user to click Link2 until the handler for Link1 is finished, why not just hide Link2 until Link1 has been clicked and the handler finishes?

Comment: I know.. but suppose I can't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"...is it possible that the alert of `#link2` start before the alert of `#link1`?"*

No. If the clicks actually happen in that order, the events will be triggered in that order.

JavaScript is single threaded, and the event systems are *synchronous*. This guarantees that the  *synchronous* portion of the first click must complete before the second click event is allowed.

If *asynchronous* code is introduced into the handler for the first click, then the first click will still begin first, but the second click could start if it takes place before the  first click's *asynchronous* code runs.

---

To simulate a super fast sequence of clicks, just have the code trigger the events.

```
var l1 = $('#link1');
var l2 = $('#link2');

l1.click();  // this alert will always come first
l2.click();
```

Comment: That's strange! `JavaScript is single threaded`, but I can do asynchronous code?

Comment: @markzzz: Asynchronous code takes place within the single thread. It's just scheduled for a later time. Let's say we use a `setTimeout` to schedule some code for `10ms` in the future. But let's also say that the code that comes right after the `setTimeout` is synchronous and long running, and takes `1000ms` to complete. The code in the `setTimeout` callback will not run in `10ms` as scheduled, but instead will need to wait for the previous long running code to complete.

Comment: Ok! But, for example, if I put .animate() in my .click() handler it start on "another thread"... do you know what I mean?

Comment: @markzzz: It doesn't start in another thread. The animation is just a series of asynchronous scheduled updates of some CSS property at a very short interval. Usually there's no long running code to block, so any other code that needs to run can complete in between the intervals. I think the default interval for an animation is `13ms`, which is usually plenty of time for other code to run. But let's say there's some code that needs to run in the middle of an animation that takes `500ms`. Your animation will suddenly be halted until that code completes.

Comment: ...[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/49KQW/) of some code that is scheduled for `10ms` in the future, but immediately after it some long running code starts, which takes `1000ms`. You'll see that the scheduled code happens in more than `1000ms` instead of `10ms`. This is because of the single thread. Remove the long running code, and it happens closer to `10ms`.